# Can I install Ubuntu alongside my windows 10 as a dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have an old enough laptop which has 64Gb internal storage and it has Windows 10 already installed on it. I am wondering do I have enough space to do a dual boot with both windows 10 and Ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very opinionated question; or how much space do you need?  I'm aware of people squeezing Ubuntu down to ~10gb (despite 25gb being minimum) by only using limited functions, never release-upgrading etc. Your usage depends on how much space is required; and how small can you get windows 10?  What software do you actually need etc?  Only you can decide that

Answer (score 0):

If it were *me,* I would use [VirtualBox](https://virtualbox.org):  a *completely free* virtual machine manager produced by none other than Oracle Corporation -- yeah, "the big database people," one of the largest and richest software companies in the world.  It runs on everything and is very efficient.  You simply install and run Linux in a *window* on your existing Windows host, without changing anything.  (VirtualBox will manage the "hard drive" for Linux using ordinary Windows files.)  I do this all the time, and it works fabulously.  To me, "dual-boot is for the birds."